# Beacon: Is it possible to run both a DAppClient and WalletClient instance together?

Tags: beacon

I’m currently working on a PoC for PoE authentication and the integration with multisig wallet (Tzsafe). For now, I basically forked beacon, added the TZIP messages, and I’m communicating through `WalletClient` , and it works pretty well with my dummy Dapp.
Now I’ll try to integrate with Tzsafe, and I’m pretty sure that I need 2 instances to achieve that: `WalletClient` for the P2P communication between TzSafe and remote Dapp, and `BeaconWallet` to communicate with the user wallet on TzSafe. The thing is, it’s impossible to have 2 instances currently, so I’m wondering, is there another way to achieve the same result?

Question from dev slack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it is possible to run both a DAppClient and WalletClient instance together, you only have to provide a storage with a different prefix so they don't access the same localStorage items. You can see an example here in the code of our debug wallet:

https://github.com/airgap-it/beacon-debug-wallet/blob/master/src/app/services/beacon.service.ts#L48-L58

```
const storage = new LocalStorage('INCOMING');
this.walletClient = new WalletClient({
  name: 'Beacon Debug Wallet',
  storage,
});
```

And the debug wallet, in case you don't know. Helps to inspect and debug beacon messages sometimes: https://debug.walletbeacon.io/